# EF - One to many relationship inside another one to many (Facebook posts/reactions)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado

I have the following entities:

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        UserName = new Name();
        UserEmail = new Email();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Gid { get; set; }
    public Name UserName { get; set; }
    public Email UserEmail { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string ImageUri { get; set; }

    public virtual User Author { get; set; }
}

public class Reaction
{
    public int ReactionId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string IconUri { get; set; }
}
```

**One** user can have **many** posts, and **one** post can have **many** reactions. **The problem is that a reaction should store a reference to its post and the user which reacted**. I could make a one to many relationship between users and posts just fine.

How can i map this relationship using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 3):

**Addition after comment at the end**

If you follow [the entity framework code-first conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) for a one-to-many relationship, you don't have to add any attributes nor use fluent API to tell entity framework what you want.

Only if you want different table names, property types, column names, or other specialties about the relations between tables you'll need attributes or fluent API.

You problem is caused because you ommited some of the one-to-many definitions in the class definitions

Your user:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // every user has zero or more Posts (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

The Post:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // every Post belongs to exactly one User using foreign key
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post {get; set;}

    // every Post has zero or more Reactins (one-to-many)
    public virtual IColleciton<Reaction> Reactions {get; set;}

    ...   
}
```

Reactions on this Post:

```
public class Reaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // every Reaction belongs to exactly one Post using foreign Key:
    public int PostId {get; set;}
    public virtual Post Post {get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And finally your DbContext:

```
public MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Post> Posts {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Reaction> Reactions {get; set;}
}
```

This is really all that is needed for entity framework to understand that you want the one-to-many relationships and to find out which properties should become foreign key. Entity framework also understands that you can't have a Reaction without a Post. If you try to Remove a Post, all its Reactions will be removed First.

I changed some items to let it be more compliant to the code-first conventinos.

- Proper pluralizaion. One `Post`, many `Posts`
- All IDs are named Id (although your Id is also according to convention). I use this, so it is always clear for every class what the primary key is, even if the class changes name.
- All items that won't become columns (like the ICollections) are virtual
- all one-to-many have a foreign key with a property name according to the conventions
- No classes have a constructor that instantiates members. After all, if you'd do a query the members would be instantiated and immediately replaced by the result of the query

One of the advantages of the ICollections it that you don't need a fairly difficulte left outer join on foreign keys if you want a User-with-his-Posts.

To get all old Users with all or some of their Posts you can use the ICollection. Entity Framework will translate this in the proper Left outer join for you:

```
var oldUsersWithManyReactions = myDbContext.Users
    .Where(user => user.BirthDay < new DateTime(2040, 1, 1))
    .Select(user => new 
    {
        // Select only the user properties you plan to use
        Id = user.Id,
        FullName = user.Name.First + User.Name.Last,

        // select the Posts of this User:
        RecentPosts = user.Posts
            .Where(post.PublicationDate > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDay(-7))
            .Select(post => new
            {
                // again select only the Properties you want to use:
                Title = post.Title,
                PublicationDate = post.PublicationDate,
                ReactionCount = post.Reactions.Count(),
            }),
        }),
    }),
});
```

**Addition after comment**

If you want a "User with all his Reactions" use `SelectMany`. This is in fact a LINQ question and has nothing to do with Entity-Framework

```
var usersWithAllTheirReactions = myDbContext.Users
    .Where (user => ...)
    .Select(user => new
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        Name = ...,

        AllReactions = user.Posts
            .SelectMany(post => post.Reactions)
            .Where(reaction => ...)
            .Select(reaction => new
            {
                ReactionDate = reaction.Date,
                Text = reaction.Text,
            }),
        }),
    });
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the Reaction have a reference to the User which reacted to a post?

Comment: It can be, but your database wouldn't be normalized anymore (google why database normalization is important). If you want a "User with all his References" use `SelectMany`